# Check graph equality using networkx isomorphic

Tags: python, graph, networkx, isomorphic

I have two graphs as follows

```
import networkx as nx

G1, G2 = nx.DiGraph(), nx.DiGraph()
G1.add_edges_from([("s1", "s2"), ("s2", "s3"), ("s3", "s4")]) # G1: 1->2->3->4
G2.add_edges_from([("s1", "s2"), ("s2", "s3"), ("s3", "s7")]) # G2: 1->2->3->7

nx.is_isomorphic(G1, G2)
```

By definition, we know the above two graphs are isomorphic, so `is_isomorphic` returns **True**.

However, I wish to check structure **equality** between two graphs, meaning nodes and edges are the same (but weights allow difference). Since `G1` and `G2` have different last node, I am looking for the `is_isomorphic` function returning **False**.

Q: Is it possible using `is_isomorphic` to identify the non-equality?

P.S.
I tried to use `iso.categorical_node_match` or `iso.numerical_node_match` or `iso.numerical_edge_match` as plug-in parameter in `is_isomorphic`:

1. [network: numerical_edge_match](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.numerical_edge_match.html)
2. [networkx: is_isomorphic](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.is_isomorphic.html)

But I am still not sure how to call these `iso` function correctly in node_match or edge_match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During comparison, node attributes are compared. By default, node attributes are a blank dictionary (and do not incorporate node label information). A quick way to fix that is to use `nx.convert_node_labels_to_integers` and specify the key for label attributes:

```py
G1_int = nx.convert_node_labels_to_integers(G1, label_attribute='label')
G2_int = nx.convert_node_labels_to_integers(G2, label_attribute='label')
print(G1_int.nodes[0])
# {'label': 's1'}
```

Now, to make sure that `nx.is_isomorphic` uses the relevant attribute information, we can specify custom `node_match` function:

```py
nx.is_isomorphic(G1_int, G2_int, node_match = lambda x,y: x==y)
# False
```